# Hibernate validator for @Embeddable

Tags: hibernate, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am having an entity that has embedded property and using Hibernate validator to validate the Entity . But validation is not performed for embedded property .

Code snippet below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FV_TBL_SOI_IGLS")
public class IGLSDataBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7274784548705371043L;

public IGLSDataBean() {

}

/*
 * @Column(name="FUND_CODE") private String fundCode;
 */
@Size(min = 0, max = 120)
@Column(name = "FUND_NAME")
private String fundName;
@Size(min = 0, max = 255)
@Column(name = "SECURITY_NAME")

     @Valid
@EmbeddedId
private SOIPK id;

@Embeddable
public class SOIPK implements Serializable {
@NotNull
@Column(name = "SEC_ID")
private String secid;

Set<ConstraintViolation<IGLSDataBean>> constraintViolations = validator
            .validate(iglsDataBean);
```

Comment: How are you validating the root entity, `Employee` ?

Comment: Updated the code snippet

Comment: Everything looks right to me, there must be some other problem, Is `secid` really null or is it blank?

Comment: This looks ok, how is Validation triggered? Which other frameworks are you using and which version of Hibernate Validator?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue, adding the annotation @Valid is not enough you also need to add something to check like @NotNull

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "FV_TBL_SOI_IGLS")
public class IGLSDataBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7274784548705371043L;

public IGLSDataBean() {

}

/*
 * @Column(name="FUND_CODE") private String fundCode;
 */
@Size(min = 0, max = 120)
@Column(name = "FUND_NAME")
private String fundName;
@Size(min = 0, max = 255)
@Column(name = "SECURITY_NAME")

@Valid
@EmbeddedId
@NotNull
private SOIPK id;

@Embeddable
public class SOIPK implements Serializable {
@NotNull
@Column(name = "SEC_ID")
private String secid;

Set<ConstraintViolation<IGLSDataBean>> constraintViolations = validator
            .validate(iglsDataBean);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to annotate the address field with `@Valid`.

Side note: Why do you identify an employee by his address? That makes very little sense.

Comment: Thanks for reply . I already tried annotating with @Valid . But , it's not working and it is just an example for easier understanding. Actual entity is different .

Comment: Then post the real code. Don't ask us to find a bug in code A by showing us code B.